# Can we put some paragraphs inside a box?

Tags: discussion, support, mathjax

I have some paragraphs, for example,

---

1. **For inline formulas, enclose the formula in `$`…`$`.  For displayed formulas, use `$$`…`$$`.**

   - These render differently. For example, type the following to show *inline* mode:
     `$\sum_{i=0}^n i^2 = \frac{(n^2+n)(2n+1)}{6}$`
     $\sum_{i=0}^n i^2 = \frac{(n^2+n)(2n+1)}{6}$
   - or type the following for display mode:
     `$$\sum_{i=0}^n i^2 = \frac{(n^2+n)(2n+1)}{6}$$`
     $$\sum_{i=0}^n i^2 = \frac{(n^2+n)(2n+1)}{6}$$
2. For **Greek letters**, use `\alpha`, `\beta`, …, `\omega`: $\alpha$, $\beta$, …, $\omega$.

   - For uppercase letters, use `\Gamma`, `\Delta`, …, `\Omega`: $\Gamma$, $\Delta$, …, $\Omega$.
   - For other Greek capital letters, use Latin `$A,`, `B`, `E$` and so on: $A, B, E$.
   - Some Greek letters have variant forms:
     `\epsilon \varepsilon` $\epsilon$, $\varepsilon$, `\phi \varphi` $\phi$, $\varphi$, and others.

---

Is there a mathjax syntax to put above paragraphs inside a box? This is to separate (and thus highlight) a theorem statement in a thread.

Thank you so much!

Comment: In the MathJax tutorial, there is an answer titled "[Highlighting equation](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/22395)". Perhaps you'll find that of use...

Comment: @TheAmplitwist I'm aware of that answer, but it only works for equations inside `$...$` or `$$...$$`.

Comment: I suppose you could use the `\text{}` command inside the math block `$...$`. (I'm not sure if that will cause any serious accessibility issues, e.g. when viewing the site using a screen reader.)

Comment: @TheAmplitwist My paragraphs usually contain many *text sentences*...

Comment: It will most likely be very complicated to typeset the sample paragraph you indicated in your post. But you could manage something short like `$$\bbox[15px,border:2px solid black] {\textbf{Theorem. } \text{If $A$, then $B$ implies $C$.}}$$`.

Comment: See e.g. [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2051711/242) with box-highlighted telescopic induction schema (highlighted so extremely because they deserve to be much better known - one should use extreme highlighing sparingly)

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness, you get borders for free with this [New Feature: Table Support](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support). Quite limited and painful to use, though.